# json parsing using url in windows phone application

Tags: json, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I want to parse this url: https://data.cityofchicago.org/api/views/xzkq-xp2w/rows.json?search=rahm and display the data in the emulator.

My code is:

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.OpenReadCompleted += new OpenReadCompletedEventHandler(downloadAboutCompleted);
webClient.OpenReadAsync(new Uri("https://data.cityofchicago.org/api/views/xzkq-xp2w/rows.json?search=rahm"), c);

private void downloadAlbumCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Error == null && !e.Cancelled)
    {
        using (StreamReader httpwebStreamReader = new StreamReader(e.Result))
        {
            var results = httpwebStreamReader.ReadToEnd();
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(results):
            var json = JObject.Parse(results);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(json):

            foreach (JObject array in json["meta"]["view"])
            {
                JObject obj = JObject.Parse(array.ToString());
                string id= (string)obj["id"];
                string name= (string)obj["name"];

                MessageBox.Show(name);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

But I am getting error in the following line:

```
foreach (JObject array in json["meta"]["view"])
```

And the error is: `An exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in PhoneApp1.DLL but was not handled in user code`

thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post a part of your `json` data just to have an idea how the structure looks like. It probably needs a cast into `JArray` with `view` as individual `JObject` of every `JArray` element.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, we shouldn't debug your code, *you* should. Simply run your application with F5 instead of Ctrl+F5 and when the exception is raised, *inspect* the code and variables and you will find your error.

So, you know what the error is, it says right there: you are doing an invalid cast. You cannot cast the result of `json["meta"]["view"]` to `JObject` in the loop because the object on the right is of `JProperty` type, and not of `JObject type`.

Simply change your loop to this:

```
foreach (JProperty property in json["meta"]["view"])
```

And it should work.

Please, try solving the problem by yourself next time, you cannot ask such simple questions here.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use foreach in json["meta"]["view"] as it is Json object in your URL.

```
 JObject obj = json["meta"]["view"];
                string id= (string)obj["id"];
                string name= (string)obj["name"];

                MessageBox.Show(name);
```

it will works great